# Incorrect result while using np.ma.allequal()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am comparing if all entries of two columns in a data frame are equal. The following is the code.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":[1,2,3,4]})
np.ma.allequal(x["a"], x["b"])
```

The execution of above code returns `False` where as values in both the columns are the same. [Here is the official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ma.allequal.html). What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you using masked array operations?

Comment: Which operation should be used in this case?

Comment: `(x["a"] == x["b"]).all()` ?

Comment: [`np.testing.assert_array_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_equal.html) ?

Comment: ```np.array_equal``` does the job. Thanks!

Comment: To address the reason numpy returns the wrong thing, `x['a']` is a `pd.Series`. Replacing the arguments to `np.ma.allequal` by their `.values` attributes (which actually are numpy arrays) returns `True` as intended: `np.ma.allequal(x["a"].values, x["b"].values)`